# How to manually import Wordpress xml

Tags: wordpress

I have exported my WP data from my local machine and I wanted to import it to the server. But it gave me this error: "413 request entity too large". I contacted my host and asked them to modify php.ini and htaccess like so:
php.ini:

```
; Increase maximum post size 
post_max_size = 64M
; Increase execution time
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 99M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

htaccess.:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

but it seems they don't want to do that. Is there a way to manually import the XML file? Where should I upload it?

Comment: By "WP Data". do you mean the full DB including all posts, acf fields etc?

Comment: all posts pages and media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way of doing this

1. Export your DB from local development via phpmyadmin, then import that db into your production domain, again using phpmyadmin
2. Export the XML file from the WP dashboard on your local site. Tools -> Export. Then on the production site, upload that XML, tools -> import. That'll bring over all your posts, pages, acfs, etc.

For both, you'll have to copy over the uploads folder from the your directory. wp-content/uploads. And upload them into the same directory.

If your urls are different from local to production. Run these SQL commands, obv change the script to match your urls

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```